# How to do a pg_dump for only tables only and not triggers and functions?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

**What I want:**
I want a pg_dump of a database (let's call the database as 'test').
In this pg_dump I want only the tables **without** the following: data, triggers, functions, sequences, etc.

**What I am doing to get what I want:**
The command I run is as follows:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -s test > dump_test.sql
```

**What I am observing:**
Then when I try to restore this dump on another server as follows:

```
pg_dump -U postgres new_amazing_test < dump_test.sql
```

I notice that part of the output of running the above command says the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE INDEX
```

**What I actually want:**
All I want is the table itself and not these triggers, functions, sequence and indexes. How do I only get the tables only?

**Other things I have tried/considered:**

1. I have tried doing this:

   ```
   pg_dump -U postgres -s -schema=\dtmvE test > dump_test.sql
   ```

   but it didn't work because the pattern needs to be a name not a \d pattern.
   See here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgdump.html for information on `-n pattern` option.
2. One thing that may solve it is to use multiple switches like this:

   ```
   pgdump -t mytable1 -t mytable2 -t mytable3 ... -t mytableN > dump_test.sql
   ```

   However, the above solution is impractical because I have some 70+ tables on my database.

**Other relevant info:**
PostgreSQL version is 13.1
Ubuntu version v16.04 (I have also tried this on Ubuntu v18.04)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe please save me.

Comment: You could write a bash script that loops through all the tables you want.  Generate the tables list with `SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r' AND <some_other_condition>`.  Then use your "multiple switches" approach to generate the dump file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would dump everything with a custom format schema-only dump (`-F c -s`) and run `pg_restore -l` on the resulting dump. That gives you a table of contents. Delete everything except the tables from that file and use it as input to `pg_restore -L` to restore exactly those items from the archive that you need.

This may not be as simple as you have hoped for, but it is certainly simpler than writing tons of `-t` options, and you may be able to automatize it.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, `-t` switches for all your tables would indeed be a solution, as it will cause `pg_dump` to dump only tables and not functions and triggers:

```
pgdump -t mytable1 -t mytable2 -t mytable3 ... -t mytableN > dump_test.sql
```

When done manually, this is impractical for databases with many tables. However, when generating these `-t` switches automatically it is a viable option:

1. Generate the list of `-t` switches for all tables in one or more schemas of your database: (the following assumes you use the Bash shell)

   ```bash
   TABLES=$(
     psql -h example.com -p 5432 -d db_name -U user_name --tuples-only -c \
       "SELECT CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) 
        FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE' AND table_schema IN ('public','auth');" | 
     xargs -I{} echo -n " -t {}"
   )
   ```
2. Make sure your list of `-t` switches looks as intended:

   ```bash
   $ echo $TABLES
   -t public.mytable1 -t public.mytable2 ... -t public.mytablen 
   -t auth.mytable1 -t auth.mytable2 ... -t auth.mytablen
   ```
3. Run `pg_dump` with the generated list of table switches:

   ```bash
   pg_dump \
     -h example.com -p 5432 -d db_name -U user_name \
     --schema-only --no-comments --no-owner --no-privileges $TABLES \
     > tables.sql
   ```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the flag `--section` as described in the [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgdump.html)

```
--section=sectionname
Only dump the named section. The section name can be pre-data, data, or post-data. This option can be specified more than once to select multiple sections. The default is to dump all sections.

The data section contains actual table data, large-object contents, and sequence values. Post-data items include definitions of indexes, triggers, rules, and constraints other than validated check constraints. Pre-data items include all other data definition items.
```

example:

```bash
pg_dump --schema-only --section=pre-data
```

Comment: This still dumps functions.

Comment: I think `pre-data` is the wrong section.  I think they meant `--section=data` to only dump table data, large-object contents, and sequence values.  Another options might be `--data-only`.  See pg_dump docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-pgdump.html